# python: IndexError: list index out of range (file = sys.argv[1])

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = sys.argv[1]
    f = FST("q0")
    #f.addState("1", True)
    #f.addState("2", True)
    #f.addState("3", True)
```

in line `file = sys.argv[1]` getting this error. can anyone please help me out.

Comment: So what arguments are you giving your script?

Answer (score 1):

The `sys.argv` list is populated only when command line arguments to the script are present. `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script you are running. `sys.argv[1]` will be the first command line argument passed to the script. You need to call your script like:

```
python SCRIPT_NAME FIRST_ARG
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running your script without arguments while it expects at least one.

`sys.argv` is the list of arguments given to the script. `sys.argv[0]` is the script itself; `sys.argv[1]` is the first actual argument. If you give no argument to the script, `1` is an out of range index.